# If $p, q$ are primes and $p$ does not divide $n-1$ and $p$ divides $n^q-1$. How to prove that $q|p-1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, factoring

If $p, q$ are primes and $p$ does not divide $n-1$ and $p$ divides $n^q-1$. How to prove that $q|p-1$.

What we can see is that $p|(n^{q-1}-n^{q-2}+\cdots -1)$. Now how do I prove that $p|q-1$

Comment: can you use Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: What can you say about the order of $n$ is a certain group of a relevant order?

Comment: Note you have switched $p$ and $q$ around in the end part of your question where you ask "Now how do I prove that $p|q-1$".